# Updating android studio gradle plugin breaks old api version desugaring

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

For a dependency update, I have to update my android studio gradle plugin to 7.3.1 or higher.

I updated

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4' -> 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
```

and

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip ->
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```

Without changing any other code, upon doing this, the app started crashing on android API version 24 caused by

```
uncaughtException
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.time.Instant
        at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
        at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:2551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType(Method.java:150)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1811)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1684)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.-wrap8(ObjectStreamClass.java)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:239)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:238)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:41)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:236)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.writeNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:711)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDescriptor(ObjectOutputStream.java:680)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1322)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1271)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1467)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1521)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1474)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:723)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:763)
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8655)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3052)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:2)
        at androidx.core.app.a.i(ActivityCompat.java:1)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$b.f(ComponentActivity.java:166)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$a.b(ActivityResultRegistry.java:35)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.a(ActivityResultLauncher.java:2)
```

It seems like desugaring of libraries like time.java from api V26 is not working correctly after the AGP update.
For reference, I have coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled turned on

```
compileOptions {

    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion
}
```

and am on

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
```

Further updating this does not fix the issue either. Any advice for how I could workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that further upgrading the desugaring library or further upgrading the Android gradle plugin doesn't work? If you meant the gradle plugin, then I suggest trying to upgrade the desugaring library to 1.2.0 which might help.

The docs say that min 7.3.1 android gradle plugin is required for 1.2.0 desugaring library, so it could be that a newer desugaring lib version might help.

Comment: As described in the post, the problem is with updating the android gradle plugin. Updating the desugaring library does not solve the issue.